# Scroll bar missing from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

For some reason on my page http://automammoth.com/shop/cart/ (please add an item to cart to see it) the scroll bar is missing from the drop down menus, so my customers cannot select the correct state or country. Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? I cannot find the correct field in the css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of the `overflow: hidden` in this CSS rule fixes your problem.

```
http://automammoth.com/wp-content/plugins/shopp/core/ui/styles/catalog.css?ver=20110511
line 47
media="screen"

#shopp form ul {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1;
}
```